# Deleting files using batch file

Tags: batch-file, filepath, delete-file

I have the following batch file snippet:

```
FOR /F %%G IN (
'dir /b /s ApprovalClassLibrary.dll Constants.dll CustomControls.dll NetSpell.SpellChecker.dll'
) do (
ECHO Deleting "%%G"
del %%G
)
```

which I am trying to use to delete any DLL files listed.

The dir command correctly finds the files as follows:

```
    C:\Users\brian\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HRActions 10.3.2\ApprovalClassLibrary\bin\Constants.dll
    C:\Users\brian\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HRActions 10.3.2\ApprovalClassLibrary\SetupFiles\publish\bin\Constants.dll
    C:\Users\brian\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HRActions 10.3.2\Constants\bin\Constants.dll
    C:\Users\brian\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HRActions 10.3.2\Constants\obj\x86\Release\Constants.dll
    C:\Users\brian\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HRActions 10.3.2\CustomControls\bin\CustomControls.dll
...
```

But when I run the script I get the following

```
    Deleting "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Visual"
    Could Not Find C:\Users\brian\Documents\Visual
    Deleting "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Visual"
    Could Not Find C:\Users\brian\Documents\Visual
    Deleting "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Visual"
    Could Not Find C:\Users\brian\Documents\Visual
    Deleting "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Visual"
    Could Not Find C:\Users\brian\Documents\Visual
...
```

It appears that the path is breaking due to the space in the directory.  How can I get this command to properly expand the path so I can delete the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `delims` phrase:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (
```

And definitely change the `DEL` to

```
del "%%G"
```

-if you don't, del will attempt to delete the list of files provide in the argument, with the usual spaces and commas as separators.

Comment: Thanks, it was the "delims=" piece that I was missing.  I had tried %%G with and without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `"Delims="` to your for statement, otherwise it will break on every space by default.